# Finding basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the B-matrix B of T is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation
$T \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    x_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{2} \\
    x_{3} \\
    3x_{3}-2x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Find all vctors of the form $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    x_{2} \\
    x_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $T(\vec{x})$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec{x}$. Then find a basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the $\mathfrak{B}$-matrix B of T is diagonal.

I solved for the first part and got $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    4 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 
\end{bmatrix}$ but I don't understand how to find the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I know that B of T is only diagonal if $T(\vec{v_1})=c_1 \vec{v_1},...,T(\vec{v_n})=c_n \vec{v_n}$ so does that mean the basis is the three vectors above? Since they satisfy that condition. Except they don't span the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Why don't these vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ according to you?

Comment: <1,0,0>,<0,1,0>,<0,0,1> span all of R^3 but you can't get <0,0,1> from the three vectors above, I think...

Comment: But you can. And they do.

Comment: They do span $\mathbb{R}^3$ since they are linearly independent (determinant different from $0$) and the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a real vectorspace is $3$. Also, note that a half times the first vector + a half times the second vector - the third vector is $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Oh... so do any three linearly independent vectors span all of R^3?

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!!

Comment: Yes. In order to know if a set forms a basis, it suffices to have that two of the following three conditions are satisfied: (1) the elements of the set are linearly independent (2) the elements span the complete space (3) there are as many elements as the dimension of your space. The reason two of them is sufficient is that the third one always follows from any of the two others.